# Script error : variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined, scope

I have a javascript file that declares the variable below:

```
var page = page || {};
```

The above file is included in another javascript file that wants to make use of page variable. I can see that variable in intellisense when trying to type it.

But at runtime, I am getting error that :

page is not defined.

I am posting more elaborate code:

First file is page.js that has just one line

```
var page = page || {};
```

Second file uses the above variable:

```
/// <reference path="page.js" />

page.current = function () {
};
```

There is final third file:

```
/// <reference path="../pagescripts/page-current.js" />
define(function () {

var Agencies = function (app, datacontext, logger, config, router) {
     var myPage = page.current;
     //The above line throws error saying page is not defined.
});
};
```

Comment: This type of _ReferenceError_ usually happens when you `"use strict";` mode without `var`

Comment: The code you posted doesn't produce that error. I assume you are trying to access `page` somewhere where it is not in scope. You should post the code where you are trying to access the variable. We need a more complete example.

Comment: @FelixCling Proof of what you said http://jsfiddle.net/5A6f4/

Comment: How are all the files brought together? Are you sure you're loading page.js  before the second file? Typically if you're defining a module over multiple files, you'd have `var page = page || {};` at the top of every file so they can be included in any order.

Comment: It seems like the third file is loaded before the other ones or something overrides `page` after the second file loaded.

Comment: @FelixKling I was not loading page.js initially. Now when I am loading it, page is available at run time but now it says current is undefined inspite of loading both the files.

Comment: To prevent errors, I have combined the contents of file 2 and file 3 into file 1. Ideally it should not be done this way. I want the files to be separate. The files should be concatenated when the page loads.

Comment: @user2585299 To make that work, just put `var page = page || {}` at the top of all three files [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23661104/227299)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern is commonly used when using the same namespace object across multiple files. By putting

```
var page = page || {};
```

at the **top of each file** that touches that namespace, you're guaranteed that `page` will point to the same object, and you can load them in any order, if your code permits.

```
// page1.js
var page = page || {};
page.doSomething = function() {};

// page2.js
var page = page || {}
page.doSomethingElse = function() {};

// page3.js
var page = page || {};
page.doThirdThing = function() {};
```

Comment: What's wrong with `var page = page || {};`? It's actually `var page; page = page || {};`. It will never throw an error.

Comment: The code the OP uses is fine. is `page` is undefined, it is an empty object. It's not the cause of this error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you load the javascript file that defines the variable before the file/script tag that uses it.

Comment: But shouldn't it default to {} if that was the case if it wasn't loaded?

Comment: @jamie it won't _default to_ `{}`, it will always be `{}`, because `page` gets initialised as _undefined_ before the `page || {}` and _undefined_ is _falsy_

Answer (score -3):

If you can not change the order of script file load for some reason, then you may use dom onready function to access this variable. As a rule of thumb, you should delay execution of your logic till dom is ready. e.g. in jQuery you can use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// application init logic
// or start execution of functions
  if(page && page.whatever) {
      page.whatever();
  }
})
```

Comment: Please don't offer jQuery solutions when it is not tagged jQuery. You don't need to bloat your website to access a variable.

Comment: jQuery reference was just an example to show how dom onready can be used.